# android studio doesn't connect with mysql db when configured with usb device

Tags: android, mysql, database, android-studio, database-connection

I am trying to connect my android app with mysql db. If I do it through emulator it is connected successfully, but when try with usb device (tablet) it doesn't. It shows this error:

```
07-29 07:12:40.651  17236-17274/com.birdorg.anpr.sdk.simple.camera.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.birdorg.anpr.sdk.simple.camera.example.AnprSdkMain$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(AnprSdkMain.java:111)
            at com.birdorg.anpr.sdk.simple.camera.example.AnprSdkMain$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(AnprSdkMain.java:75)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
07-29 07:12:40.886  17236-17236/com.birdorg.anpr.sdk.simple.camera.example I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x51b46238) fps:9.96, dur:1003.96, max:101.63, min:99.31
07-29 07:12:41.412  17236-17236/com.birdorg.anpr.sdk.simple.camera.example E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.birdorg.anpr.sdk.simple.camera.example.AnprSdkMain has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{417c01a8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-219,114} that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.birdorg.anpr.sdk.simple.camera.example.AnprSdkMain has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{417c01a8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-219,114} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:409)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:218)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
            at com.birdorg.anpr.sdk.simple.camera.example.AnprSdkMain$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(AnprSdkMain.java:89)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
            at com.birdorg.anpr.sdk.simple.camera.example.AnprSdkMain.onClick(AnprSdkMain.java:72)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17446)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

public class AnprSdkMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //php login script location:

    //localhost :
    //testing on your device
    //put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    //or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
    //private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/login.php";

    //testing on Emulator:
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/anpr/webservice/login.php";

    //testing from a real server:
    //private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/webservice/login.php";

    //JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //setup input fields
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        //setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        //register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AnprSdkMain.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(AnprSdkMain.this, Lista.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else if(success == 0){
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.toString());
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(AnprSdkMain.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? As it works with emulator but not with tablet. I tried to change `http://10.0.2.2/anpr/webservice/login.php` to `http://127.0.0.1/anpr/webservice/login.php` but the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way. If you are on a wifi network, try with the IP address provided to your device by the router. And also you need internet permission on your manifest.

Comment: I have intenet permissions. What to do in the case I want to connect with online phpmyadmin server? I can't put an ip

Comment: What do you mean by online server? Then it should have an IP address or a domain name definitely.

Comment: I mean where to put index.php and login.php ? It's the first time i do this, pls give me some instructions

Comment: It has an domain name but don't know where to put index.php and also at http://10.0.2.2/anpr/webservice/login.php what should put?

Comment: I don't understand your doubt clearly. Do you have your own server bought from a vendor? Or you are running on your local machine? You can have both the php files on the same directory.

Comment: the problem is this: I have an config.php which make the connection with mysql server (online) and $username = "username"; 
    $password = "pass"; 
    $host = "host"; 
    $dbname = "db";

Comment: The above I think is ok. And I have this config.php inside www/anpr/webservice. Now at "http://10.0.2.2/anpr/webservice/login.php"; what should I put? And also I want to know if someone in another comp can access the db even if doesn't have config.php inside www?

Comment: you can't connect this way. Either move your files to an online server where you bought your hosting space or test it with your emulator instead of device or find your device IP address if you are on a wifi network